# Drive H-Bridge using analog signal instead of pwm?

Tags: h-bridge, l298

Is it possible to drive an H-Bridge like the L298n using actual analog signals rather than digital PWM signals?

If not, what would be the equivalent to an H-Bridge that allows for this?

Comment: What you want is a linear amplifier, and there are many, many options to consider. Too many to discuss here, based on the limited information you have provided.

Comment: @Elliot  Maybe he wants an on/off H-bridge with an analog input for duty cycle.  The question allows that interpretation too.  The question is worded ambiguously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The equivalent in the analog world would be a DC power amplifier with bipolar output. We use such things (rack mounted good for something like 1kW) to drive voice-coil actuators.

Comment: Could this also be used to drive two opposing pull-solenoids with connected shafts to 'imitate' a voice-coil?

Comment: Probably? As usual, you get better answers if you give us a complete picture...

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to drive an H-Bridge like the L298n using actual analog signals rather than digital PWM signals?

My understanding of the question/requirements is different than  @Spehro's and @Elliot's.  The H-bridge shall have on/off outputs [not the linear outputs].  The duty cycle of the H-bridge shall be set by an analog voltage.

A power stage like an L298 will not accept an analog signal by itself.  There would have to be a small signal circuit converts analog input to PWM with varying duty cycle.  LTC6992 is an example if such converter.  Some 555 circuits can convert analog to duty cycle too.

Yes, it's possible to control the duty cycle of an H-bridge with an analog voltage.  In fact, this is done in some DC-DC converters.

Comment: So you'd still need a ADC inbetween - nah, that's not what I mean, but thank you for your answer!

Comment: @user1282931  Analog to duty cycle conversion can be done with more primitive (almost entirely analog) circuits than an ADC.